# Carousel images appear above my footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im using a jquery carousel plugin to show some images. It is working fine, but Im having a strange effect and I dont see any way to solve this issue.

My images, when the height of screen is smaller, the images appear above my footer as you can see in my image...

Do you see any way to fix this?

[image]

**My jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_caroussel/jquery.featureCarousel.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var carousel = $("#carousel").featureCarousel({
    });

    $("#but_prev").click(function () {
      carousel.prev();
    });
    $("#but_pause").click(function () {
      carousel.pause();
    });
    $("#but_start").click(function () {
      carousel.start();
    });
    $("#but_next").click(function () {
      carousel.next();
    });
    });
</script>
```

**My html:**

```
<div class="carousell">
<div class="carousel-container">
    <div id="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-feature">
            <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" width="620" height="420" alt="Image Caption" src="http://placehold.it/620x420"></a>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum
                    <a class="link2" href="#">Read + <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-feature">
            <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" width="620" height="420" alt="Image Caption" src="http://placehold.it/620x420g"></a>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum
                    <a class="link2" href="#">Read + <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-feature">
            <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" width="620" height="420" alt="Image Caption" src="http://placehold.it/620x420"></a>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>
                    Lorem Ipsum
                    <a class="link2" href="#">Read + <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="carousel-left"><img src="img/arrow-left.png" width="30" height="30" /></div>
<div id="carousel-right"><img src="img/arrow-right.png" width="30" height="30" /></div>
</div>
```

**My css:**

```
.carousell{
    position:relative;
    height: 20px;
}
.carousel-container {

  margin:0 auto;
}
#carousel {
  background-color:#none;
  position:relative;
  font-size:12px;
  font-family: Arial; 
  top:250px;
}
.carousel-image {
  border:0;
  display:block;
}
.carousel-feature {
  position:absolute;
  top:-100px;
  left:-1000px;
  border:5px solid #B21203;
  cursor:pointer;

}
.carousel-feature .carousel-caption {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#B21203;
}
.carousel-feature .carousel-caption p {
  margin:0;
  padding:5px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}
.tracker-summation-container {
  position:absolute;
  color:#fff;
  right:48px;
  top:380px;
  padding:3px;
  margin:3px;
  background-color:#B21203;
}
.tracker-individual-container {
  position:absolute;
  color:white;
  right:48px;
  top:410px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.tracker-individual-container li {
  list-style:none;
}
.tracker-individual-container .tracker-individual-blip {
  margin:0 3px;
  padding:0 3px;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#DDD;
}
.tracker-individual-container .tracker-individual-blip-selected {
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-color:#B21203;
}
#carousel-left {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-460px;
  left:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#carousel-right {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-460px;
  right:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: it's not clear what's the goal?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im trying that my carousel 620x420 images  dont appear above my footer!

Comment: I think that popup is always showing in the middle of the screen, no matter what size it is. I guess you're using dummy text for the main content, but in production if you main content is rather tall, then you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Are you using bootstraps footer fixed to bottom class?  if so you need to increase the z-index of your footer to higher than that of the carousel